# Why are uncertainty and entropy sampling functions giving me the same results?

Tags: python, sampling, entropy, uncertainty

I'm currently comparing sampling techniques in Python and seeing how effective oversampling is on the classification of the dataset after these sampling techniques are applied. I'm trying to compare uncertainty sampling and entropy oversampling, which I understand are similar but should still give different results. I'm using the modAL Python package.

```
from modAL.uncertainty import uncertainty_sampling, entropy_sampling
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np

X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,2,6,2,8,3,4,8,3,2,7,3,67,4,3,1,7,67,49]
X = np.array(X)

_, X_uncert = uncertainty_sampling(classifier = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo', gamma='auto', probability=True), n_instances=5, X=X)
_, X_ent = entropy_sampling(classifier = svm.SVC(decision_function_shape='ovo', gamma='auto', probability=True), n_instances=5, X=X)

print("UNCERTAINTY")
print(X_uncert)
print("ENTROPY")
print(X_ent)
```

Both of these sampling techniques give the same results:

```
UNCERTAINTY
[ 7  3 67  2  4]
ENTROPY
[ 7  3 67  2  4]
```

modAL also has a margin sampling function, which again gives the same results.
Any help on why this is happening?

Thanks